# Best way of dealing with a sort of animation of nodes in JavaFX

Tags: java, animation, javafx

I am making an application using JavaFX and I would like to make a sort of animation where I can scale a height of a node ( in this case it can be an Rectangle filled with ImagePattern ) on a Canvas.

I was thinking maybe putting it on Canvas, but if there is a better approach to it, I would like to hear it too. I am not quite sure from where to start and it seems to me I got lost in search for it.

As it is now, I have a VBOX filled with many rectangles but I would also like to be able to scale a height of each node individually.

I would like to know if this is possible and if yes, I would like to hear possible solutions to my issue. Thanks.

**UPDATE 2:**

This is something I was looking for.

An image of what I want to achieve

[image]

Comment: If you have not touched custom nodes, this looks like a good situation to learn.

Comment: This is actually something I was looking for! :-)

Comment: When I was asking this Q. SO didn't offer me this solution, sorry it turned out to be a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to scale the heights dynamically, i.e. from within Java code, then use

```
myVBox.setPrefHeight(200);
```

or

```
myRect.setHeight(200);
```

Look [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/shape/Rectangle.html#method.summary) for more methods for Rectangle objects.

Comment: That's not a problem at all. I was thinking more of a scenario where on canvas I could click on a node and extend it to a height moving mouse up or down.

Comment: Let's be clear here. Do you want to change the size of child nodes independently of the size of the canvas node itself ? Do you have any sample code for the effect you want to produce ?

Comment: No, this is not at all something I was looking for. The thing is that I don't have a code since I came here for a solution. Please, take a look at my updated Q. with an image.